# How to execute a R script file from java

Tags: java, r, rserve, jri

I would like to call an R script from Java. I have done google searches on the topic, but almost all of the results I have seen would require me to add a dependency to some third party library. Can anyone show me a good way to accomplish the same thing without adding any dependencies to my code?

I'm setting up a new application which runs R script file from java using the following line

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Thiru\\Desktop helloWorld.R");
```

but when I run the application I am getting following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RenjinServlet] in context with 
path 
[/REngineCheck] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Thiru\Desktop": 
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at org.r.Check.RenjinServlet.doGet(RenjinServlet.java:102)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter (WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke 
(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke 
(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke 
(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke 
(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke 
(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke 
(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke 
(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service 
(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process 
(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process 
(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun 
(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run 
 (NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run 
  (TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
```

Comment: If your windows is not configured to use `Rscript` to run files ending in `.R`, you may need to do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\path\to\Rscript.exe C:\Users\Thiru\Desktop\hellowWorld.R")`. (I'm not familiar enough with java to know for sure if that should be a string with the cmd and all args, or if you need to pass a list with the cmd as the first, and your R script as the second element.)

Comment: Dear @r2evans, It's not working I am getting file not found exception, but when I run  like this in CMD I am getting the out put in cmd.    E:\E Drive\Softwares\R docs\R-3.5.1\bin\x64>Rscript C:\Users\Thiru\Desktop\helloWorld.R

Comment: What happens if you try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\E Drive\Softwares\R docs\R-3.5.1\bin\x64>Rscript C:\Users\Thiru\Desktop\helloWorld.R")`?

Comment: @r2evans, I am getting file not found exception when I run like this.

Comment: My guess (again, not a java guy) is that it had to do with including both the executable and its argument(s) in one string. Do you know how to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`? I do not.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your path in a bracket like

> ("your_path\Rscript.exe your_path\filename.R")

If you set the environment, you can use `Rscript`

Example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.1\\bin\\x64\\Rscript.exe C:\\Users\\Thiru\\Desktop\\helloWorld.R");
```